# Issue with TABLE or DIV padding on Mobile

Tags: css

I have an issue on a page when viewed on a mobile device.

[This page](http://flxclone.windermereroadies.com/race-manage/104/) (since issue has been solved this page won't be accessible any longer), when viewed on a browser looks perfect. But when I view it on my mobile device (iPhone using latest Chrome app version) the page looks broken on the right margin (as per the screenshot below).

If I decrease the cell padding values it works, but it depends on the mobile screen size. The smaller the screen the less padding I can have.

If I remove the cell padding it seems to work on all screen sizes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common CSS problem. In your table, there are too many columns for the width to accommodate, so div.table is overflowing from its container.

To fix, wrap div.table inside another div. Set the outer div to:

```
width:100%;
overflow:auto;
```

div.table will now stay within the boundaries without breaking the right margin, but will need to be side-scrolled to be fully viewed.